# Error response from Slooce API to validate mobile numbers

Tags: ubuntu, server, coldfusion

We are facing issues randomly while getting response from Slooce API to validate mobile numbers.

Error message says connection failure while establishing connection.

Here's the example of one of the API call:-

> "09/07/22","02:40:44","","Starting HTTP request
> {URL='https://americalearns.cloud.sloocetech.net/slooce_apps/spi/americalrn80/13232523652/AMERICALEARNS/messages/supported',
> method='POST'}"

Here's the screenshot of the response received

[image: Error response]

Comment: This looks like a DNS resolution error. Make a dns query for that domain name from a terminal command line on your server and check if the server is properly resolving that domain name.

Comment: Agreed. I doubt this is anything to do with CF; it won't know anything about DNS resolution, it'll just be passing this to the underlying server. Possibly a question for serverfault?

Comment: okay i will check

Comment: I have checked with nslookup command , its properly resolving to the domain

Comment: On the CF server, can you change the `.hosts` file to manually set the server?

Comment: You may consider switching your DNS services to Cloudflare or Google public DNS servers.  I have experienced local ISP or cloud server DNS servers that will intermittently fail.  @James suggestion to use the hosts file is a good one.  It should resolve faster than a DNS server.  Note: some public DNS servers may have query limits.

Comment: hey should I do changes on .hosts file or /etc/resolv.conf

Comment: @JamesAMohler how can I do that , what changes should I do in the .hosts file